# which is the difference between physical and default hostname?

Tags: networking, hosting

I saw that I can use different types of hostnames

```
<hostname physical="true"> technical_name  </hostname>
<hostname default="true">  link  </hostname>
<hostname> name </host>
```

can someone tell me which is the difference between these lines? and also what happens if I set physical or default hostname on false ?